# Composer DNS problem using docker on MacBook Pro

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, dns, composer-php

I'm having some troubles running my docker application on a M1 Macbook with macOS Montery 12.3.1.

The first time I initiate my container I have no problem installing all the packages.

However as soon as I try to build it again with this time a composer.lock I get the following error :

[image: DNS Error]

I already tried some of the solution I saw here like adding DNS to Docker config (this does not work for me, still having the same issue) :

[image: DNS config]

Here is my DockerFile for more information :

```
# the different stages of this Dockerfile are meant to be built into separate images
# https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#stop-at-a-specific-build-stage
# https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#target


# https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact
ARG PHP_VERSION=7.4
ARG OPENRESTY_VERSION=1.17.8.2
ARG VARNISH_VERSION=6.4


# "php" stage
FROM php:${PHP_VERSION}-fpm-alpine AS api_platform_php

# persistent / runtime deps
RUN apk add --no-cache \
        acl \
        fcgi \
        file \
        gettext \
        git \
    ;

ARG APCU_VERSION=5.1.18
ARG MONGO_VERSION=1.9.0
RUN set -eux; \
    apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
        $PHPIZE_DEPS \
        icu-dev \
        libzip-dev \
        zlib-dev \
        curl-dev \
        openssl-dev \ 
    ; \
    \
    docker-php-ext-configure zip; \
    docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) \
        intl \
        mysqli \
        zip \
    ; \
    pecl install \
        apcu-${APCU_VERSION} \
        mongodb-${MONGO_VERSION} \
    ; \
    pecl clear-cache; \
    docker-php-ext-enable \
        apcu \
        opcache \
        mongodb \
    ; \
    \
    runDeps="$( \
        scanelf --needed --nobanner --format '%n#p' --recursive /usr/local/lib/php/extensions \
            | tr ',' '\n' \
            | sort -u \
            | awk 'system("[ -e /usr/local/lib/" $1 " ]") == 0 { next } { print "so:" $1 }' \
    )"; \
    apk add --no-cache --virtual .api-phpexts-rundeps $runDeps; \
    \
    apk del .build-deps

COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

RUN ln -s $PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini-production $PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini
COPY docker/php/conf.d/api-platform.prod.ini $PHP_INI_DIR/conf.d/api-platform.ini

RUN set -eux; \
    { \
        echo '[www]'; \
        echo 'ping.path = /ping'; \
    } | tee /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/docker-healthcheck.conf

# https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer-allow-superuser
ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1
# install Symfony Flex globally to speed up download of Composer packages (parallelized prefetching)
RUN set -eux; \
    composer global require "symfony/flex" --prefer-dist --no-progress --no-suggest --classmap-authoritative; \
    composer clear-cache
ENV PATH="${PATH}:/root/.composer/vendor/bin"

WORKDIR /srv/api

# build for production
ARG APP_ENV=prod

# prevent the reinstallation of vendors at every changes in the source code
COPY composer.json composer.lock symfony.lock ./
RUN set -eux; \
    composer install --prefer-dist --no-dev --no-scripts --no-progress --no-suggest; \
    composer clear-cache

# do not use .env files in production
COPY .env ./

# copy only specifically what we need
COPY bin bin/
COPY config config/
COPY migrations migrations/
COPY public public/
COPY src src/

RUN set -eux; \
    mkdir -p var/cache var/log; \
    composer dump-autoload --classmap-authoritative --no-dev; \
    composer run-script --no-dev post-install-cmd; \
    chmod +x bin/console; sync
VOLUME /srv/api/var

COPY docker/php/docker-healthcheck.sh /usr/local/bin/docker-healthcheck
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-healthcheck

HEALTHCHECK --interval=10s --timeout=3s --retries=3 CMD ["docker-healthcheck"]

COPY docker/php/docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint

ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint"]
CMD ["php-fpm"]


# "nginx" stage
# depends on the "php" stage above
# The OpenResty distribution of NGINX is only needed for Kubernetes compatiblity (dynamic upstream resolution)
FROM openresty/openresty:${OPENRESTY_VERSION}-alpine AS api_platform_nginx

RUN echo -e "env UPSTREAM;\n$(cat /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf)" > /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf
COPY docker/nginx/conf.d/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

WORKDIR /srv/api/public

COPY --from=api_platform_php /srv/api/public ./


# "varnish" stage
# does not depend on any of the above stages, but placed here to keep everything in one Dockerfile
FROM varnish:${VARNISH_VERSION} AS api_platform_varnish

COPY docker/varnish/conf/default.vcl /etc/varnish/default.vcl

CMD ["varnishd", "-F", "-f", "/etc/varnish/default.vcl", "-p", "http_resp_hdr_len=65536", "-p", "http_resp_size=98304"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are using a pretty outdated version of Symfony Flex. Since some days, their server flex.symfony.com is no longer available. This was [announced some months ago](https://symfony.com/blog/symfony-flex-is-going-serverless), and updating the package `symfony/flex` to any more recent version (any after v1.17, which was released in October 2021) should resolve the problem.

Since Flex tries to run even when doing the update, you need to run:

```
composer update symfony/flex --no-plugins --no-scripts
```

Comment: Thanks that works now, I updated the very old version of symfony/flex I had and then cleaned and installed my vendor folder